# SASS: How to exclude part of selector

Tags: html, css, sass

I am creating polyfill of :before pseudo element for IE7:

```
.my-div:before,
.my-div .ie7-before {

}
```

I want to add a flag that will exclude part `.my-div .ie7-before` from generated CSS file  when it's required. e.g.:

UPD.: here is how I want it to work:

```
$ie-enabled: true;

// @if $ie-enabled SASS should generate

    .my-div:before,
    .my-div .ie7-before {
        color: red;
    }

// otherwise

    .my-div:before {
        color: red;
    }
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the question... but as I see it is too simple so I guess i'm getting it wrong... I would need a more straight explanation! Sory, I'm argentinean!

Comment: Thank you, basically and I want is to exclude part `my-div .ie7-before` from generated stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a variable to indicate whether or not to emit your ie7 styles.  Adjust your class names as appropriate:

```
$ie7: false;

.my-div:before {
    background: #CCC;
}

@if $ie7 {
    .my-div .ie-7 {
        @extend .my-div:before;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.my-div:before {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

When `$ie7: true`, the output will be this:

```
.my-div:before, .my-div .ie-7 {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to understand your question, but you can include a class by using `@extend .my-div;`

Comment: Thank you for help, I updated the question, hope it's more clear now.